# Pattern Recognition

Tags: pattern

[image: Q6]

[image: Q2]

Can someone help me solve this IQ-test-like puzzle and predict the pattern? There are two questions above - please provide your answer of choice and reasoning for each.

Here is another one I found to be harder:

[image: Q17]

**Puzzles are from [here](http://www.psychometric-success.com)**

Comment: Links go down, can contain malware, etc. Can you please copy the contents of the puzzle into your question? Thanks!

Comment: this is imgur site . Same site that runs behind stackexchange hosting so no malware

Comment: But if you use `stack.imgur.com`, which you can easily do via the editing interface, the image will be nicely embedded in the question. And it doesn't have all the visual ad and social network noise that the normal `imgur.com` has.

Answer (score 6):

1

> B - Flipped along an axis running from the upper left corner to the bottom right

2

> D - Little stick alternates from left side to right side, big sticks alternates through apart, both down, both up, apart, both down, both up ...

3

> A - Left column is the original image, middle column is some modification, and for the right column. If the colour changed the block is removed, if the colour did not change then the block gets recoloured.

Answer (score 3):

For the first one,

> I would go with B.
> The line is only rotated 90 degrees, so only A,B and D are possible.
> The 2 squares are either rotated 180 degrees or were reversed on the axe of up-left corner to down-right corner.
> None of the choices are the result of a 180 degree rotation so the later must be correct.
> Since the 2 squares are ON the reverse axis, they are not affected and stay the same.

For the second one,

> I would go with B
> The small line only switch from right to left every time, so only B,C or D are possible.
> This is hard to explain and a bit of a stretch, but the way I see it, there is a "left mode" and "right mode", they both alternate between 2 and 3 line.  First image is "left mode" and has three lines, next image is "right mode" and has 2 lines, back to "left mode" with only 2 lines, then back to "right mode" with 3 lines, so next would be "left mode" with 3 lines. As I said, a little bit of a stretch, but it's all I got so far.

For the third one,

> The answer is A.
> The first image is the base,
> The second image has a few random changes to some nods,
> The third image reverse the color of all the nods that were not changed and remove all the nods that did change.

Comment: Thanks . Could you do the second one as well and here is a new link to another question which I found to be a lot tough . http://imgur.com/a/VyR4v Would like to hear you thoughts

Comment: All are correct except for second . See this link http://aptitudetest.tripod.com/3.pdf  . Question is #2 and the answer key is at the last

Comment: I also chose the same answer as you for second question but it is the orientation of lines , that is causing issue

Comment: I think B and D are valid answers. B is valid if you take both long sticks as separate elements. The upper stick from the first image goes UP, DOWN, UP, DOWN... The lower stick of the first image goes DOWN, DOWN, UP, UP, DOWN, DOWN... But the deal with B is that the cycle's end is never confirmed. For D the cycle restarts at a point.

Comment: I think B and D are valid answers. B is valid if you take both long sticks as separate elements. The upper stick from the first image goes UP, DOWN, UP, DOWN... The lower stick of the first image goes DOWN, DOWN, UP, UP, DOWN, DOWN... But the deal with B is that the cycle's end is never confirmed. For D the cycle restarts at a point.

Answer (score 3):

6) is:

> B. Rotate $90^\circ$ clockwise and then flip across the vertical.

2) is:

> D. The small line goes left, right, left, ... The verticals go both, bottom, top, both, bottom, top, …

Another for 2)

> B. Small line goes left, right. The are two verticals, the initial top one goes top, bottom, top, bottom, the lower one goes bottom, bottom, top, top,.

17) is:

> Both rows and columns follow:
>  $\begin{array}{c|c|c|c} +&bl&B&W\\ \hline bl&bl&bl&bl \\ \hline B&bl&W&bl\\ \hline W&bl&bl&B \end{array}$

Answer (score -2):

the answer is:

> B. Rotate 90 degrees clockwise then reflect then flip vertically